# How to make this image appear on top of the div

Tags: html, css, image, position, overlap

I've never had problems with this before but it seems now that this image doesn't want to appear on top of the div. I've even tried z-index but it shows underneath.

Image is this: http://www.flaticon.com/free-icon/menu-button-of-three-lines-outline_60310

```css
#menu-square {
 height: auto;
}
#top-menu {
 height: 3em;
 width: 100%;
 background-color: black;
}
```

```html
<!--All content-->
<div id="sb-site">
 <div id="top-menu">
  <!--Toggle sidebar menu------------------------------------------------->
  <a href="#" class="sb-toggle-left button"><img src="../menu54.svg" id="menu-square"></img></a>
 </div>
</div>
```

Comment: 1.5% of 3em is **very** small.

Comment: I listed the image link right below my answer
http://www.flaticon.com/free-icon/menu-button-of-three-lines-outline_60310

and if you scroll over on the html the tag is after src

Comment: Oh does it take the % of the div? I was referring to the % of the page

Comment: Yep, % height is of **parent** not page.

Comment: Nothing is wrong with your code at all. The image is black, so is your background, so you can't see the image in the first place. And second, 1.5% is very very small. Change your background color, and set a px size.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is that your background is the same color as your picture. See code below, I've changed the background-color and it's working fine.

You don't need `z-index` in this situation. Also, `<img>` tags don't need to be closed: `<img src="..." />`.

```css
#menu-square {
  height: 10px;
  width: 10px;
}
#top-menu {
  height: 3em;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: AliceBlue;
}
```

```html
<!--All content-->
<div id="sb-site">
  <div id="top-menu">
    <!--Toggle sidebar menu------------------------------------------------->
    <a href="#" class="sb-toggle-left button">
      <img src="http://cdn.flaticon.com/png/256/60310.png" id="menu-square" />
    </a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Oh wow thank you that worked. I realized my mistake about the size but even after I fixed that the image was still behind the div. Your code works but I don't fully understand it. The inside of the image is white so shouldn't it still show with a black background?

Comment: @Bob Your picture is a .png or .svg which means that the background is transparent. The image is only three black paths that form a hamburger icon, you don't have any white in it. My code is the same as yours except that I've changed your black background-color to AliceBlue (which is a color in css, like white or black).

Comment: Geez I'm very forgetful today I forgot about the transparency. Thank you to everyone for being so helpful. This was my first question and it was answered quickly.

Answer (score 0):

Change background color of `#top-menu`, change your `image size % to px,`

http://jsfiddle.net/6xsa1vhg/2/